# Handling Playback Output to Speaker/Bluetooth

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, avfoundation

I'm trying to playback an audio file and handle any changes that might occur. If I start playing an audio file it will play on the bluetooth speakers. If I turn off the speakers, it plays on the phone speaker. **However**, if I then turn the bluetooth speakers back on, the notification method is run but it doesn't see the bluetooth speakers.

Any time I turn the bluetooth speakers on, the notification is alerted, the method runs but the bluetooth speaker isn't listed in the outputs.

Notification:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("myRouteChangeSelector"), name: AVAudioSessionRouteChangeNotification, object: nil)
```

with the method code being:

```
func myRouteChangeSelector(){

    let currentRoute = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().currentRoute
    for route in currentRoute.outputs {
        println("PortType \(route.portType), Description \(route.portName)")
        if route.portType == "BluetoothA2DPOutput"{
            println("Bluetooth detected")
            let portDescription = route as! AVAudioSessionPortDescription
            AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setPreferredInput(portDescription, error: nil)
        } else {
            println("No Bluetooth, speaker only")
            AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().overrideOutputAudioPort(AVAudioSessionPortOverride.Speaker, error: nil)
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to set an output as input.  You'd want to search through currentRoute.inputs instead of outputs to find portType AVAudioSessionPortBluetoothHFP instead of AVAudioSessionPortBluetoothA2DP, and set that as your preferred input.

A2DP == output only
HFP == input and output

Have a look at the documentation/header comments for AVAudioSession::setCategory/withOptions/mode and associated parameters; they will heavily influence what route the OS ultimately chooses.